# Stop bash completion from being smart and ignoring extensions

Tags: bash, autocomplete

Why will bash not complete the bar.dat on the unzip line - the file is in the current directory. Is bash reading file extensions and trying to be helpful?

```
[a@localhost:~/tmp]$ echo "Hello World" > foo.txt
[a@localhost:~/tmp]$ zip bar.dat foo.txt
  adding: foo.txt (stored 0%)
[a@localhost:~/tmp]$ unzip bar.dat   <---- won't complete bar.dat
Archive:  bar.dat
replace foo.txt? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename: n
[a@localhost:~/tmp]$ file bar.dat
bar.dat: Zip archive data, at least v1.0 to extract
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is done by `bash` completion `_install_xspec` function.  Your
local setup may vary but typically various file extensions completions
are controlled by `_xspecs` array.  Do this:

```
$ set | grep _xspecs
```

You'll see a gigantic wall of text that starts with `_xspecs=(`.  There will also be a section for `unzip`:

```
[unzip]="!*.@(zip|[ejsw]ar|exe|pk3|wsz|zargo|xpi|s[tx][cdiw]|sx[gm]|o[dt][tspgfc]|od[bm]|oxt|epub|apk|do[ct][xm]|p[op]t[mx]|xl[st][xm])"
```

As you see there is no `dat` on this list.

Comment: Thanks, I got why it was doing it, I just wanted to stop it. Now I have a place to look.